# Explain why we need to add 1 to nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(column_name_blob),0) OR nvl(vsize(column_name),0)

Tags: oracle

I was searching for finding the length of a row in Oracle, when I came across http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_find_length_clob.htm.
Can anyone kindly explain why we need to add 1 to `nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(column_name_blob),0)` OR `nvl(vsize(column_name),0)`?

Like:

```
select
nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(CASE_DATA),0)+1 +
     nvl(vsize(CASE_NUMBER   ),0)+1 +
     nvl(vsize(CASE_DATA_NAME),0)+1 +
     nvl(vsize(LASTMOD_TIME_T),0)+1
     "Total bytes per row"
from
    mytab
where
    case = 123;
```

Comment: Just speculating here, but I assume the computation attempts to measure the total size in bytes, including overhead. Add 1 to account for the field terminator character (which is not part of the data length, but it is part of the "row length" if you need to estimate storage space for whatever reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A row is stored (more or less) as

```
 [row header]
 [length of column1] [column1 data]
 [length of column2] [column2 data]
 [length of column3] [column3 data]
 ...
```

Where `[row header]` consists of `[flag byte][lock byte][columns count]`, ie 3 bytes.

Let's look at simple example - this is a dump info of one row from data block dump:

```
tl: 44 fb: --H-FL-- lb: 0x1 cc: 3
col 0: [22]
 4d 61 6e 20 57 68 6f 20 53 6f 6c 64 20 54 68 65 20 57 6f 72 6c 64
col 1: [ 3] c2 14 47
col 2: [13] 42 6c 6f 6f 64 79 20 47 6f 6f 64 21 21
```

Here

- `tl` - total length of the row - 44 bytes - oracle doesn't store it, oracle just calculated it for us
- `fb` - flag byte
- `lb` - lock byte
- `cc` - column length
- [N] - length of the column data
- and column data after that

Let's calculate the length of this row manually:

- Row header: flag byte + lock byte + columns' count = 3 bytes
- Column 0: column length(1 byte) + 22 b = 23 bytes
- Column 1: column length(1 byte) + 3 b = 4 bytes
- Column 2: column length(1 byte) + 13 b = 14 bytes

So total = 3 + 23 + 4 + 14 = 44 bytes and we can see it's equal to `tl`, so we calculated it correctly.

Of course, in case of migrated or chained rows you will have more row headers, so you will need to add their lengths too.

In short: you can use this simplified formula:  3 (row header) + columns count + vsize() of all columns values, for example, for a table with 3 columns (without LOBs) considering nulls:

```sql
select
   3 -- row header
  +nvl(vsize(col0),1) -- even if other columns are nulls too, null will be stored as 1 byte (0xFF)
  +nvl(vsize(col1), case when col2 is null then 0 else 1 end) -- 0 if there is no data after this column
  +nvl(vsize(col1),0) -- oracle doesn't store trailing NULL-valued columns in row
from t
```

**But! it's not about LOBs:**
First of all it depends on [ENABLE or DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adlob/creating-new-LOB-column.html#GUID-6378560B-4305-496A-95A7-1FDFB6719FDC) option.

> LOB columns store locators that reference the location of the actual LOB value. This section describes how to enable or disable storage in a table row.
>
> Actual LOB values are stored either in the table row (inline) or outside of the table row (out-of-line), depending on the column properties you specify when you create the table, and depending the size of the LOB. The ENABLE | DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW clause is used to indicate whether the LOB should be stored inline (in the row) or out-of-line.
>
> If ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW is set, the maximum amount of LOB data stored in the row is 4000 bytes. This includes the control information and the LOB value.

So in case of `Inline` and short lobs (<3960bytes) you can count their length, but not for long lobs: first of all you need to count a length of lob locator + lob index + count a number of required chunks to store data and multiply it on chunk size. And do not forget about LOB `retention` (or `pctversion`): You may will need to count also old versions of your LOBs

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A row is stored (more or less) as

[length of column1]
[column1 data]
[length of column2]
[column2 data]
[length of column3]
[column3 data] and so forth.

although there's various boundary conditions in terms of nulls, LOBs etc.

Also, each row has a lock byte to indicate if that row is currently being locked by a transaction.

So the formula above is not *exactly* correct, because a length could more than 1 byte but its probably close enough.

However, typically finding the length of a row is the precursor to finding the total size of a table, and in that case, you may as well just use NUM_ROWS * AVG_ROW_LEN, or BLOCKS from USER_TABLES to get a rough estimate, or BYTES from USER_SEGMENTS.

If you want a deep dive into how rows are stored in a block, here's a video on the topic

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffDZlGdSWJQ

Comment: Actually I have a table containing records w.r.t. different Business groups. So, I want to get the size of all the records of a particular Business group from that table, not the entire table. For Example let's say Business Group 1 has 10000 records, Group 2 has 200000 records. So, I want to know the record size w.r.t. Group 1 and Group 2 separately.